# Joining columns in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Consider the following SQL table:

```
id | col1 | col2
----------------
1  |  a   |  b
2  |  c   |  d
```

What query would get me the distinct result set of `a,b,c,d`? I know I can do:

```
SELECT distinct col1 FROM `table` UNION
SELECT distinct col2 FROM `table`
```

but that seems ugly (and doesn't get me the *entire* distinct set); plus, I'm not sure how I can do further processing with that result set. Any better idea?

Comment: As far as I know, I believe this is your best option

Comment: If your `col1` and `col2` represent the same data, which I assume they do since you are trying to group them together into a distinct set, then **fix your data model** so it's normalized appropriately.

Comment: I'm curious - why does your query not return the entire distinct set?

Comment: @JNK - how would you normalize this table?

Comment: @Yuval - Since `col1` and `col2` represent the same data, why do you need it in two fields?  Put it in one field, and you can simply `SELECT DISTINCT Col12` and problem solved.

Comment: @JNK - they have semantic meaning. They are all foreign keys to the same table (`a, b, c, d` are all the same *things*) but `col1` and `col2` have significance in our application.

Comment: @Yuval - then you could create a lookup table that has `id, type, value`, where type is whatever `col1 / col2` represent now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Beauty is in the eye of the beholder. `UNION` is [one of the five primitive operators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra) of Codd's relational algebra and for me it is a thing of beauty.

Your SQL code should indeed get you the entire distinct result set; In fact, you should be able to omit the `DISTINCT` keywords and the code should still get you the entire distinct result set (hint: a set does not contain duplicate members).

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps not better, but different:

```
select distinct sub.val from (
  select col1 as val from table
  union all
  select col2 as val from table
) as sub
```

Comment: Error: `#1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias`

Comment: @Yuval - just change it to `Select distinct sub.val FROM (...) as Sub`

Answer (score 0):

You could probably use LAG and LEAD functions to get the values of the previous and next row in a single result set.  Check out this article:

http://explainextended.com/2009/03/10/analytic-functions-first_value-last_value-lead-lag/